# Add Timer() for Progressbar inside Asynctask

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask

I want to display a circle indeterminate progress bar for 5secs inside my validation asynctask, the problem is after 5secs my app crashes

The error is : "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

I'm using Timer for my progressbar.

```
  class VerifyStudIDTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // use doInBackground() to make network calls, the returned value is
    // sent to onPostExecute()
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {

        String StudID = data[0];

        if (StudID.replace(" ", "").isEmpty()) {
            f8 = true;
            return "1";
        }
        else if (StudID.contains(" "))
        {
            f8 = true;
            return "2";
        }
        else if (!StudID.matches("\\d+"))
        {
            f8 = true;
            return "3";
        }
        else if(checkIfSameStudID(StudID))
        {
            f8 = true;
            return "4";
        }
        else
        {
            f8 = false;
            return "5";
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loading_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        long delayInMillis = 5000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loading_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, delayInMillis);

        tilStudID.setErrorEnabled(true);
            switch(result)
            {
                case "1":  tilStudID.setError("You can't leave this empty.");break;
                case "2":  tilStudID.setError("No spaces allowed.");break;
                case "3":  tilStudID.setError("Numbers only.");break;
                case "4":  tilStudID.setError("Student ID already used.");break;
                default: tilStudID.setError(null);tilStudID.setErrorEnabled(false);break;



            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `Timer` in Android.  It's a legacy Java class that was included in the SDK to support existing libraries.  It's a heavyweight solution that launches an extra thread and requires extra code to work properly, as you've discovered.  For simple delays and intervals like this, create a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and use `Handler#postDelayed(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve desired behavior you'll need to update your view in UI thread.
To do that you mast call `runOnUiThread` method and pass runnable that updates view to it.

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    loading_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }, delayInMillis);
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I did what Kevin said. (Use Handler)